# How to retain the same browser view/page when a controller function is called in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that contains a download link on the hompage. When clicked it is supposed to download an Excel report from AWS S3 bucket.

This is my controller function:

```rb
  def download
      s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')
      obj = s3.bucket('mybucket').object( my_report_file_name)
      obj.get(response_target: my_report_file_name)

      puts "S3 download code execution complete"

      respond_to do |format|
        format.all { render :nothing => true, status: :ok }
      end

  end
```

I use this in my view:

```rb
  <%= link_to 'Download Report', download_path, remote: :true %>
```

When I do a `render :nothing =>true, status: :ok` as shown above, this is what happens - when I click the download link on my homepage, a blank browser page opens in a new tab.

I don't want this to happen. I would like to call my controller function and would like to retain the home page of my app as is without any change.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: replace `respond_to` func with `return`

Comment: Um don't you actually want to send the [downloaded file](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#sending-files) to the client? What you really need here is just to add the `download` attribute to the link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Comment: @max - would you be able to provide some example for your points please? I am very mush interested in sending the downloaded files to the client - yes. I am using a `link_to` (I have updated the question with the code I use for this). Can I use the `download` attribute in my `link_to`? My current controller method downloads the file in the server machine. Can just one attribute in `link_to` change this behavior and get the file downloaded to the client browser instead of the server machine? Pls advise.

Comment: Read the mdn documentation I linked to. The download attribute just changes the behavior of the link so that it opens a download prompt instead of attempting to open a new page. You can add additional html attributes with link_to by passing a hash see the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  def download
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')
  obj = s3.bucket('mybucket').object( my_report_file_name)
  obj.get(response_target: my_report_file_name)

  puts "S3 download code execution complete"

  return

end
```

and the download link should be remote:true

```
<%= link_to 'download', download_path, remote: :true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'Download Report', download_path, download: true %>
```

> **download**
>   This attribute instructs browsers to download a URL instead
>   of navigating to it, so the user will be prompted to save it as a
>   local file. If the attribute has a value, it is used as the pre-filled
>   file name in the Save prompt (the user can still change the file name
>   if they want).
>   - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

To send a file in the response use send_file or send_data.

```
def download
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2') 
  obj = s3.bucket('mybucket').object( my_report_file_name) 
  obj.get(response_target: my_report_file_name) 
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.all { send_file: my_report_file_name } 
  end 
end
```